# PyFlink - DataStream API - Missing module

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I'm trying to start with the DataStream API, but have a missing module.

Any idea what's wrong ?

**Version**

Python 3.7.9

```
python -m pip install apache-flink
```

**Code**

```
from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringEncoder
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pyflink.common.serialization
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataStream API is not supported yet in PyFlink. This is planned for Flink 1.12, with the initial work described in [FLIP-130](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=158866298).

Sorry if you were misled by the master version of the documentation. If you still want to try the Python DataStream API, you can [build PyFlink from source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/flinkDev/building.html#build-pyflink).

Comment: Thanks Marta. Since there are only few weeks left until 1.12 will be out, I'd rather wait ;)